# Printing multiple objects in different classes

Tags: java, overriding

The details in this example isn't that important just trying to figure out how I can solve this, I have 3 separate classes Person , Interests and Location. all are objects, a person would have an list of interests and each interest will have a list of locations, i'm using a toString to print my person object and the interest but I can't figure out how to print out the locations of each interest. Do i need to overload my toString?

```
public class Person{
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Interest> interests = new ArrayList<Interest>();

    public Person(String name, ArrayList<Interest> interests) {
        this.name = name;
        this.interests = interests;
    }   

    public void addInterest(Interest newInterest) {
        interests.add(newInterest);
    }

    public Interest getInterest(int indexOfInterest) {
        return interests.get(indexOfInterest);
    }

    public ArrayList<Interest> getInterests() {
        return interests;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String result = getName() + " ";
        for(Interest interest : interests) {
            result += interest.getName() + "(" + interest.getDangerRating() + ")" + " ";
        }
        return result.trim();
    }
}
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
public class Interest {
        private int dangerRating;
        private String name;
        private ArrayList<Location> location = new ArrayList<Location>();

    public Interest (int dangerRating, String name, ArrayList<Location> location) {
        this.dangerRating = dangerRating;
        this.name = name;
        this.location = location;
    }
    public int getDangerRating() {
        return dangerRating;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
public class Location {
    private String location;
    public Location (String location){
        this.location = location;
    }
    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reccomend making a toString for each class. That way you can call a Location toString in the Intrest's toString, then the location toString in the Person. Also, the ArrayList class has its own toString that prints all the items in the array.

Currently you only have one toString and you are manualy getting the data for each. So for example:

(In the Location Class):

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "Location: " + location;
}
```

(In the Interest Class):

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
     return "Danger Rating: " + dangerRating +
            "Name: " + name +
            "Location: " location.toString(); //Note, the name location is confusing here since it is an ARRAYLIST of locations.

}
```

(In the Person Class):

```
@Override
public String toString() 
{
    return "Name: " + name +
           "Intrests: " + intrests.toString();
}
```

(In the Main Class):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
     Intrest[] intrests = new Intrest[4]; //TODO: Create intrests, currently they are all null.
     Person thePerson = new Person("Eddie", intrests);

     System.out.println("Person Info: " + thePerson.toString());
}
```

Comment: how do I go about calling this in my main, i  did this i just wasnt sure how i would call them since theyre all separate but i guess thats the point of the override

Comment: The point of the override tells Java to use this function instead of the one in the base class. Its an advanced topic called "Inheritance and Polymorhism" but I wouldn't worry about that for now (https://cs.calvin.edu/activities/books/processing/text/13oop.pdf).

So if you want to call this in your main, I would assume your main class has a person object or a list of person objects? If so you can call toString on those objects.

Answer (score 0):

Learn to use your tools: every IDE can generate an overriden `toString()` method and they are good for the most cases.

```
public class Location {
    // ...
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Location{" +
                "location='" + location + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}

public class Interest {
    // ...
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Interest{" +
                "dangerRating=" + dangerRating +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", location=" + location +
                '}';
    }
}

class Person{
    // ...
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" +
              "name='" + name + '\'' +
              ", interests=" + interests +
              '}';
    }
}
```

I would advise you to stick to your IDE's default `toString()`s, because that will make your `toString()`'s look consistent acros all your projects, and soon they will be familiar for you and easy to read.

Comment: So if I call toString in my main what happens? will it call each of them or, sorry my IDE doesn't have that feature on mac

Comment: It will subsequently call toString on all the objects inside your Person. Btw, what IDE do you use? a notepad?

Answer (score 0):

In your Person class, you call interest.toString() in a loop for all interests

```
public String toString() {
    String result = getName() + " ";
    for(Interest interest : interests) {
        // add this function to print interest stuff
        result += interest.toString(); 
    }
    return result.trim();
}
```

In your Interest class, you'll want a toString or similar method like so

```
public String toString(){
    String s = "";
    //print stuff for interest i.e. s+= what you want to add
    //loop through locations associated with Interest
   for(Location l : this.location ){
       // print what you want in location.toString()
       // add this funciton to your Location class
       s += l.toString()
   }
   return s;
}
```

And then in your Main you just need to call
    person.toString() and it will loop through and print everything for you.